# what is the most appropriate structure of this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I want to say that I banged my head against wall because some one said something stupid,

how to put it in a sentence?

Is

```
I banged my head against wall 'on' this stupidity?
```

or

```
I banged my head against wall 'for' this stupidity?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentence one is definitely out.  Sentence two can be saved with some word changes.  For example,

> "I banged my head against the wall over this stupidity."

Or,

> "I banged my head against the wall because of this stupidity."

Or,

> "I reacted to this stupidity by banging my head against the wall."

Or,

> "I reacted to his/her/their stupidity by banging my head against the wall."

Or,

> "This/his/her/their stupidity made me bang my head against the wall."

Or,

> "I felt like banging my head against the wall because of this/his/her/their stupidity."

Or,

> "I banged my head against the wall in frustration for his/her/their stupidity."

Comment: Or *I banged my head against wall **over** this stupidity*.

Comment: @bib:  Good point.

Comment: ...or, *in frustration **at** his stupidity* ?

Comment: @jez: Good point. Don

Answer (score 2):

You could say it many different ways. And wall is not the only object you can bang your head against, there are many others. You could bang it against your office desk, against the hard surface of a concrete road, a brick or any other object that seems to make your head bleed:)

> I banged my head against the wall because of his stupidity.
>
> Because of his bad behavior, I banged my head against the wall.
>
> Because of his rude behavior, I banged my head against the wall.
>
> His stupidity made me bang my head against the wall/door/rock.